# How is c3p0 configured for a hot/warm standby Postgresql server?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, c3p0

I am considering creating a postgresql setup with a [hot/warm standby instance](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) so that my application is not affected by a database server downtime, and also to have a fast backup of the main server.

I suppose the simplest solution to detect the master would be to change DNS:

- Application connects to jdbc:postgresql://database.example.com/testdb
- database.example.com points to master's IP
- If master stops responding, DNS changes database.example.com to point to backup server 1. In the meantime, backup is triggered to become primary

I have a few questions:

1. Can c3p0 be configured with a non-IP url?
2. Will this work in terms of c3p0/jdbc connections? Connections with the master will break, and I am not sure how the connection pooling works in this situation. Does it simply clear the connection pool, reattempts a connection after a while and acquires the connections from the backup-turned-primary when it does?
3. Does this have any effect in hibernate (e.g. session cache), or will it be completely agnostic of what is underneath?

Finally, I am also open to different suggestions in terms of making the master/slave switch when the master becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are hiding the switch of servers behind DNS as you propose, and if that scheme would work without pooling, c3p0 should have no problem with it. c3p0 can handle any URL your JDBC driver can handle. Typically (and certainly for postgresql) there is no requirement that the database address be an hard IP, DNS name are fine and very common.

To make your scheme work, simply make sure that you have configured some reasonable kind of [connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing). c3p0 will know nothing about your DNS switch. It will just acquire and make available Connections. But when your main server is down, c3p0 will detect that those Connections are broken and retire them. It will replace them with new Connections, which will quietly be from the secondary DBMS.

My main concern with what you propose is caching. You'd have to be careful to configure your DNS not to cache the name you are switching at all, and it is possible that the Postgres JDBC driver might do the DNS lookup just once and cache internally. That might be pretty hard to work around.

Comment: Thanks for the input Steve. Although I haven't tried (and someone correct me if I'm wrong), but I think that the DNS cache is solved with the name's TTL in the nameserver configuration - if one sets it low enough (e.g, 1/2 minutes) it means that the service will be down for that time, until the cache expires and the service (in this case the JDBC driver) is forced to fetch the ip address from the nameserver.

Comment: (yeah, i think very short TTL should limit DNS caching. you'll just have to try to see how well it works!)